# What are the advantages of dynamic configuration based form templates?

Tags: frameworks, user-interface, templates, forms

When developing an application which presents the user with many similar forms for data entry, a common approach is to build a framework for defining the form structure in a standardised configuration file (or database tables). What are the actual advantages of this approach over writing the forms by hand directly in the appropriate view format for the stack you are using?

Comment: While the question appears to solicit an opinion, it could be answered with ideas based on solid metrics.  Downvote is unfair.

Answer (score 3):

None in my view.

The danger with the dynamically generated forms approach is that the meta-language for defining a form becomes just as complex as the language you would use to create a hand written form.

At this point its just as easy to write the forms by hand as to create the dynamic template for them.

Additionally, the template creating process may well have skipped a number of steps that you would naturally do with a hand written form, such as versioning and testing.

In the worst case scenario you will find yourself 'hand crafting' forms in your company's legacy, 'organically grown' and very buggy dynamic form template language for years to come.